# Best way to run a check periodicly?

Tags: android

I am about to write a task which will be run once in about 1 - 10 minutes.
This task uses the GPS. However I am not sure about the best way to do this.
Is it better to use a Service in the background with a sleep or timeout of some sort? OR am I better off using the AlarmManager Class from the android SDK?

Keep in mind it is important the task is always run (cannot afford a task to be missed because of android freeing up resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) -- see the section "Class Overview". An Intent will be sent to your program and will automatically start it if it got destroyed.

There are no hard guarantees for a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) -- [it can get destroyed under extreme memory pressure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle). Usually not an issue, so I guess it depends on how paranoid you are about that. Also, if a Service does get destroyed, I think Android tries to restart it whenever possible.

The AlarmManager doc also suggests [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class. Give that a look also.